# How to optimize livechats in a livestreaming mobile app?

Tags: android, youtube, chat, live-streaming, system-design

We have to optimise chats in live stream in a mobile app, the chats can be very fast e.g. 100 chats per second. I want to ask what are some common practices to optimise the mobile app for the same wrt performance and memory? Also how does youtube handles this so efficiently ? FYI : the mobile app is built in native android.